# Vulkan SDK - Unable to locate package

Tags: 20.04, package-management, sdk, vulkan

I am using **Ubuntu 20.04LTS**.

The following commands have been attempted:

```
wget -qO - http://packages.lunarg.com/lunarg-signing-key-pub.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget -qO /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lunarg-vulkan-focal.list http://packages.lunarg.com/vulkan/lunarg-vulkan-focal.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vulkan-sdk
```

However despite all of these commands, there is no output and I cannot install Vulkan SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't included the output of any of those commands.  It's not clear whether you're saying that the `vulkan-sdk` package isn't installing or that the tools you're using that are looking for the SDK aren't finding it.

Have you run the steps for "Verify the SDK installation" on the getting started [page](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.3.216.0/linux/getting_started_ubuntu.html)?  It suggests you run `vkvia` first.  If you run that and get

```
$ vkvia 
vkvia: command not found
```

then you probably should have seen an error message on one of the installation commands you ran, and you should debug that.

On the other hand if you get something like

```
$ vkvia
VIA_ERROR:   Vulkan failed to find a compatible driver.
```

Then the problem isn't with the Vulkan SDK, but with your Vulkan driver.

If `vkvia` spits out a bunch of information and not an error, then your system has the Vulkan SDK installed just fine, and you need to figure out what your actual problem is (like why can't your tools find it).

Comment: There is no output when I tried the commands there are no error messages. On the other hand, I’m getting command not found for vkvia.

Comment: the `wget` commands have the quiet flag turned on `-q` but the apt commands should produce some output.  if you're not seeing any you're not actually running the commands.

Comment: turns out the terminal basically skipped the second command, I never noticed it. Running `vkvia` now opens the demo app. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: Ok, I get what probably happened.  You copied that block of code and pasted the entire block into a terminal.  Unfortunately the `apt` executable consumes anything on stdin, so the second `apt` command wouldn't have actually executed but not generated an error.

Comment: Yes I figured that out. Thank you for your help!